How to generate a schedule for multiple races (and racers) in Excel
I've tried to answer this question myself and scoured SO for any relevant information but I'm still stuck and don't know where to start so hopefully someone can help!
I run several Scalextric race nights a year for a friend and ideally would like a spreadsheet that can easily generate the race schedule for the night given some simple inputs and then also be used to track the scores/positions for each race. At the moment I have been doing this on the fly by manually generating a race schedule for each event and tracking scores as we go which obviously takes time and is only as good as the humans generating it (we have occasionally had issues where some people were scheduled for more races than others or were placed twice in one race). We usually have more racers than we have lanes to race in (e.g. 10 people turn up but only 6 can race at a time) so we need a fair schedule that ensures a) everyone races the same number of times and b) everyone races in each lane. Using the example above we would run 10 races to ensure each of the 10 people raced once in each lane 1-6 but this can change. An example of this schedule:

Ideally I was thinking functionality like this:

Input the following information - Names of Racers (from which can be derived number of racers), number of lanes to race (sometimes we race 2, 4 or 6 lanes), number of races.
Run a macro to generate the race schedule which replaces the example above with a matrix showing race number across the top and lane number down the side, with names populated in each position rather than having the use a manual list like below.
For each race either run a macro or have an input to score which lane came 1st/2nd/3rd etc. which then auto populates a score table giving results per racer.

I'm quite happy coding up points 1 and 3 but I have no idea how to go about point 2 - at the moment the best I've achieved is randomly picking names from a list and putting 6 of them in a column 10 times but there's no error checking for how many times each person is picked etc.
EDIT: Apologies for not including my research in the original post - I've been spending my time trying to solve this problem and I have reached the following code:
Private Sub schedule()
last_row = Sheets("Info").Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row
Dim racerslist()
Dim index As Integer
Dim racer As String
Dim nolanes As Integer
Dim srch1 As Range
Dim srch2 As Range
Dim cel As Range


nolanes = Sheets("Info").Cells(2, 2).Value
ReDim racerslist(last_row - 2, 0)
For i = 0 To last_row - 2
    racerslist(i, 0) = Sheets("Info").Range("D" & i + 2)
Next
Sheets("Schedule").Select

For i = 1 To last_row - 1
    For j = 1 To nolanes
         index = Int((last_row - 1) * Rnd)
         racer = racerslist(index, 0)
            
            Set srch1 = Range(Cells(2, i + 2), Cells(j, i + 2))
            For Each cel In srch1
                If InStr(1, cel.Value, racer) > 0 Then
                    setfound = 1
                End If
            Next
            Set srch2 = Range(Cells(j + 1, 3), (Cells(j + 1, i + 2)))
            For Each cel In srch2
                If InStr(1, cel.Value, racer) > 0 Then
                    setfound = 1
                End If
            Next
            
            If setfound = 1 Then
                j = j - 1
                setfound = 0
            Else
                Cells(j + 1, i + 2).Value = racer
            
            End If
        
    Next
Next

End Sub

This code does the job somewhat by randomly generating a racer for each race and lane, then checking that racer has not already been put in that race and has not raced on that lane before by checking for extra instances of this person in the same row and column. Unfortunately it gets stuck in an infinite loop towards the end of the schedule as it reaches a position where there is no viable race that can be put together from those that are left.

My VBA skills is pathetic but I think you can do it like this:
First, write out a table for 10 races, 10 Lanes, like below (this table is copied from one of those Sudoku games online)




R I
R 2
R 3
R 4
R 5
R 6
R 7
R 8
R 9
R 10




Name1
L1
L2
L3
L4
L5
L6
L7
L8
L9
L10


Name2
L10
L1
L2
L3
L4
L5
L6
L7
L8
L9


Name3
L9
L10
L1
L2
L3
L4
L5
L6
L7
L8


Name4
L8
L9
L10
L1
L2
L3
L4
L5
L6
L7


Name5
L7
L8
L9
L10
L1
L2
L3
L4
L5
L6


Name6
L6
L7
L8
L9
L10
L1
L2
L3
L4
L5


Name7
L5
L6
L7
L8
L9
L10
L1
L2
L3
L4


Name8
L4
L5
L6
L7
L8
L9
L10
L1
L2
L3


Name9
L3
L4
L5
L6
L7
L8
L9
L10
L1
L2


Name10
L2
L3
L4
L5
L6
L7
L8
L9
L10
L1



If there are only 4 lanes, remove Lane5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 in the table:
(You can use conditional formatting or some simple Excel formulas to do this if you don't feel up to writing codes)

If there are only 6 lanes, remove Lane7, 8, 9, 10 in the table:

Here is one way to do it using MAKEARRAY and RANDARRAY functions in MS365:

The formula in cell D2:
=LET(
    num_racers, B1,
    num_lanes, B2,
    available_lanes, SEQUENCE(num_lanes),
    lanes, MAKEARRAY(
        num_racers,
        num_racers,
        LAMBDA(r, c,
            LET(
                lane, IF(r <= c, c - r + 1, c - r + num_racers + 1),
                IF(OR(lane = available_lanes), "L" & lane, "")
            )
        )
    ),
    racers, "Name" & SORTBY(SEQUENCE(num_racers), RANDARRAY(num_racers, 1, 0, num_racers, FALSE)),
    races, "Race" & SORTBY(SEQUENCE(1, num_racers), RANDARRAY(1, num_racers, 0, num_racers, FALSE)),
    VSTACK(HSTACK("", races), HSTACK(racers, lanes))
)

MAKEARRAY is used to generate the Sudoku like n*n table. RANDARRAY is used to shuffle Racers' name and Races randomly.

Thanks for the answer Rachel. This is essentially what I've had to do as a stop gap to generate a race schedule. Ideally I'm looking for something that would allow me to generate a schedule on the fly as I don't necessarily know how many people are turning up until the event. The other thing I was ideally looking for was a slightly more "random" generation of racers - using this example you are nearly always going to have Racer1 in the lane next to Racer2 etc, whereas it is better if we can mix that up a bit.

@ChrisBirmingham, I updated the answer. I used excel formulas in MS365. I believe MAKEARRAY in office365 can be translated into a double for loop in VBA, as for randomness, I think you can call worksheet function RANDARRAY from VBA? (I am not very familiar with that myself).

Thank you for this - I've not had a huge amount of experience in using formula rather than VBA but I'll have a play with your solution and see how I get on.

@ChrisBirmingham the random shuffling of names is from MS official example https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sortby-function-cd2d7a62-1b93-435c-b561-d6a35134f28f
